# Counter Strike Source disable automatic reload

Tags: counter-strike-source

When emptying a clip in Counter Strike Source, the weapon get's automatically reloaded.

Is it possible disable the automatic reload so you have to press the reload button yourself when the clip has been emptied?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why?

Answer (score 7):

Looking through the entire [Counter-Strike: Source Commands List](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console_Command_List), I would say no.